# Jmeter JDBC Connection Configuration Parametrization of Database URL for accessing SQL Database

Tags: database, jmeter

Anyone knows how to parametrize Database URL under JDBC Connection Configuration.

> Database URL: jdbc:sqlserver://ovh-sql1:1433;DatabaseName=user_1
>   JDBC Driver Class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

I want to parametrize DatabaseName=**user_1**

Normal parametrization is not working here. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable for database name and configure it.

Here is the example:

```
Database URL: jdbc:mysql://${mysql_hostname}:${mysql_port}/${mysql_database}
JDBC Driver Class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Username: ${mysql_username}
Password: ${mysql_username}
```